# Объясните функционал операторов % и === в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, типы-данных, операторы

Условие задачи вывести числа, которые делятся на 3 и на 5 из массива a = [1..30]
Задача практически решена, но я не могу понять зачем нужно использовать % и === 0. Так как % делит с остатком, а === проверяет тип. Объясните пожалуйста. Вот код:  https://codepen.io/1rocky12/pen/qBbQPzw

```js
let out = document.querySelector(".out");
let out1 = document.querySelector(".out1");

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
let outStr = "";
let outStr1 = "";

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 3 === 0) {
        outStr += a[i];
    }
    else if (a[i] % 5 === 0) {
        outStr1 += a[i];
    }
}
out.innerHTML = outStr;
out1.innerHTML = outStr1;
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="out"></div>
        <div class="out1"></div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

if (a[i] % 3 === 0) Разберем это условие

a[i] % 3 - получаем остаток деления на 3, допустим 9%3 = 0, 10%3 = 1.

=== -  строгое сравнение, истинна только в том случае, если типы сравниваемых значений являются одинаковыми (к примеру: string-string, number-number).

Соответственно в вашем случае if (a[i] % 3 === 0) означает, что если остаток от деления числа a[i] на 3 строго равен нулю(по-русски если число делится на 3 без остатка), то выполнить необходимое действие.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне ясно. Только одно мне не ясно. Зачем здесь строгое равенство оно же не сравнивает на равенство чисел а на тип данных. То есть 0 === 0  это число. Получается можно поставить вместо 0 любое число

Comment: @Rocky "0" == 0 => true, "0" === 0 => false, "1" == 0 => false, "1" === 0 => false, 1 === 0 => false

Comment: Нет, с точки зрения логики оно работает как ==, но у js есть некоторые особенности с работой с типами данных. Т.е. возникают вопросы null == udefined, null == null, '0' == 0. И чтобы точно ничего не путалось у js есть строгое сравнение и в нем 0 === 0 - истина, а '0' === 0 - ложь, и 5 === 0 - ложь. Т.е. кроме логического сравнивания двух чисел, он сравнит и типы данных.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне все ясно

Comment: Разве может результат `a[i] % 3` вернуть не числовое значение? Если не может, то для сравнения с константой `0` достаточно и  `==`. Я не прав?

Comment: В данном случае не может. Но best practice использовать ===, это пошло из-за отсутствия строгой типизации в js и на практике очень может облегчить жизнь)